# A citizen of eSwatini

Tags: single-word-requests, demonyms

**eSwatini** (officially the **Kingdom of eSwatini**) is the new name of [**Swaziland**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaziland). What should one call a citizen of eSwatini **in English**?

> A citizen of eSwatini is called *a[n]* _____.

<s>I can think of the following candidates: *a liSwati*, *a Swati*, *an eSwatini*, *a Swazi*.</s>

I'm not asking for an invented word. Just for the word that is appropriate now (after the country's name-change).

Comment: The wikipedia website, linked to by @user3850720, gives 'liSwati', which, in a sense, is _the_ final answer. Is there something more that you want? Since it is so new to English, it's hard to tell if it'll catch on. Local linguistic nuances are generally hard to get accepted generally. For example, 'Kiswahili' is supposed to be the name of the language, but almost entirely in English is the term 'Swahili' used. Having a different and unexpected prefix for each of person, people, language _and_ country is a lot to ask. I wonder what the news bureau's have decided on?

Comment: I suspect that 1) all the news agencies which have an Africa desk are having discussions about this 2) I bet they're having the same questions. My guess is (as to what is most natural is 'a Swati' or 'someone from eSwatini'. (the first for ease in remembering, the second for ). The eSwatini government has probably been asked what they want English speakers to use, too, so surely there's an 'official' version.

Comment: All Wikipedia sites list the demonym as Swazi.  If they previously said something else, then it must have been changed to something else and then changed back (as I recall it was Swazi before).  So at least "Swazi" is deliberate here.  Wikipedia may not be definitive, but if we can't find a clear answer, I don't think you'll have to be embarrassed if you're wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swazi_people), the term would be ***liSwati***.

> A citizen of eSwatini is called a ***liSwati***.

Comment: Isn't that the term in [Swazi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liSwati)? I see no evidence that it's used in English (however, the name change of the country only happened a few weeks ago).

Comment: Some corroboration on the gov't website: "AS THE NATION PREPARES TO CAST ITS VOTES IN THE COMING MONTHS, WE ENCOURAGE EVERY **LISWATI** TO FULLY PARTICIPATE IN THE NATIONAL ELECTIONS", http://www.gov.sz/images/speech2018.pdf. They also use the plural 'EMASWATI' there. (The whole speech was written in capitals.) The document seems to be made on 16 Feb 2018.